# alloted groups are duplicated

Tags: php, mysql

I am building this product for practice and I can not fix a problem. I am selecting members from the database and I can not call them uniquely. It is a model for attendance and it does not get unique once I call "allotted groups." I would appreciate it if someone helps me get unique when trying to take the attendance with members in the database.

Code is shown below:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AttendanceModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function get_students($id = null)
    {
        $teacher_id = user()->id;
        $alloted_groups = user()->alloted_groups;
        $alloted_groups = str_replace(",","|",$alloted_groups);
        $attendance_cas_group = $this->session->userdata('attendance_cas_group');

        if($attendance_cas_group){
            $alloted_groups = $attendance_cas_group;

            // first check if attendance is taken for the group
            $today_attendance = $this->db->where(['attendance_date' => date('Y-m-d'),'teacher_id'=>$teacher_id,'cas_item_id'=>$alloted_groups])->from('attendance')->count_all_results();

            if($today_attendance > 0){
                $records = [
                    'data' => [],
                    'message' => 'You have already taken attendance for this group students'
                ];
                return $records;
            }

            $query  = "SELECT s.*,c.selected_cas_items FROM app_students AS s";
            $query .= " LEFT JOIN app_cas_submissions AS c ON s.id = c.student_id";
            $query .= " LEFT JOIN app_attendance AS a ON a.student_ids = s.id";
            //$query .= " WHERE FIND_IN_SET(" .$alloted_groups. ",selected_cas_items)";
            $query .= ' WHERE CONCAT(",", selected_cas_items, ",") REGEXP ",('.$alloted_groups.'),"';
            //$query .= ' WHERE c.selected_cas_items LIKE "%'.$alloted_groups.'%"';

            if($id){
                $query .= " AND a.id =".$id;
            }else{
                //$query .= " AND a.id IS NULL";
            }

            $records    =   $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

            if(count($records) == 0){
                $records = [
                    'data' => [],
                    'message' => 'There is no student in your group'
                ];
            }else{
                $records = [
                    'data' => $records,
                    'message' => ''
                ];
            }
            return $records;
        }else{
            $records = [
                'data' => [],
                'message' => 'Please select the CAS group first'
            ];
        }
        return $records;
    }


    public function get($id)
    {
        $current_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $teacher_id = user()->id;
        $attendance = $this->db->where(['id'=>$id])->get('attendance')->row();
        if($attendance)
        {
            
            return $attendance;
        }else{
            return tableObject("attendance");
        }
    }


    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert_batch("attendance",$data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($data)
    {
        $this->db->update_batch("attendance",$data,'id');
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        $user_id = user()->id;
        $account_type = user()->account_type;

        $start      =   (int)$this->input->post("start");
        $length     =   (int)$this->input->post("length");
        
        $length     =   ($length)?$length:10;
        
        $columns        =   $this->input->post("columns");
        $order          =   $this->input->post("order");
        $order_by       =   (isset($columns[$order[0]["column"]]))?$columns[$order[0]["column"]]['data']:"id";
        $direction      =   (isset($order[0]["dir"]))?$order[0]["dir"]:"desc";
        $teacher_id = user()->id;
        $this->db->select("a.*,IF(teacher_id = ".$user_id.", '1', '0') AS edit_attendance")->from("attendance as a");

        if($account_type == 'teacher')
        {
            $this->db->where("teacher_id",$teacher_id);
        }else if($account_type == 'student'){
            $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$user_id.",student_ids)",1);
        }

        if($this->input->post('cas_items')){
            $this->db->where("cas_item_id",(int)$this->input->post('cas_items'));
        }

        if($this->input->post('attendance_date')){
            $this->db->where(["a.attendance_date"=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('attendance_date')))]);
        }

        $search         =   $this->input->post("search");
        if(isset($search["value"]) && !empty($search["value"]))
        {
            $this->db->where(["a.attendance_date"=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($search["value"]))]);
        }

        if($account_type == 'teacher'){
            $attendance_cas_group = $this->session->userdata('attendance_cas_group');
            if($attendance_cas_group){
                $this->db->where("cas_item_id",(int)$attendance_cas_group);
            }
        }

        //$this->db->join('cas_submissions as s','s.student_id=a.student_ids');
        
        $this->db->order_by($order_by." ".$direction);
        $this->db->limit($length,$start);
        
        $records    =   $this->db->get()->result_array();

        if(count($records) > 0)
        {
            foreach($records as $key => &$val)
            {
                $student_ids = explode(",",$val['student_ids']);
                $list = [];
                foreach($student_ids as $k => $v){
                    $student = $this->db->where(['id'=>$v])->get('students')->row();
                    if($student)
                    {
                        if($account_type == 'student'){
                            if($student->id == $user_id){
                                $list[] = $student->first_name . ' ' . $student->last_name;
                            }
                        }else{
                            $list[] = $student->first_name . ' ' . $student->last_name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $val['student_ids'] = implode(",",$list);
            }
        }
        return $records;
    }
    
    public function get_total_records()
    {
        $teacher_id = user()->id;
        $account_type = user()->account_type;
        $this->db->select("COUNT(a.id) as TotalRecord")->from("attendance as a");

        if($account_type == 'teacher')
        {
            $this->db->where("teacher_id",$teacher_id);
        }else if($account_type == 'student'){
            $this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$teacher_id.",student_ids)",1);
        }

        if($this->input->post('cas_items')){
            $this->db->where("cas_item_id",(int)$this->input->post('cas_items'));
        }

        if($this->input->post('attendance_date')){
            $this->db->where(["a.attendance_date"=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('attendance_date')))]);
        }

        $search         =   $this->input->post("search");
        if(isset($search["value"]) && !empty($search["value"]))
        {
            $this->db->where(["a.attendance_date"=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($search["value"]))]);
        }

        if($account_type == 'teacher'){
            $attendance_cas_group = $this->session->userdata('attendance_cas_group');
            if($attendance_cas_group){
                $this->db->where("cas_item_id",(int)$attendance_cas_group);
            }
        }
        $total_record   =   $this->db->get()->row();
        if($total_record)
        {
            return $total_record->TotalRecord;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    public function getCategoryDropDown($id)
    {
        $categories     =   $this->db->where("id !=",$id)->get("departments")->result();
        $catArray   =   ["0"=>"-- Select Category --"];
        if(count($categories) > 0){
            foreach($categories as $key=>$val){
                $catArray[$val->id]     =   $val->title;
            }
            $categories     =   $catArray;
        }
        return $categories;
    }

    public function get_cas_items()
    {
        $categories     =   $this->db->where("parent_id !=",0)->get("cas")->result();
        $catArray   =   ["0"=>"-- Select Item --"];
        if(count($categories) > 0){
            foreach($categories as $key=>$val){
                $catArray[$val->id]     =   $val->title;
            }
            $categories     =   $catArray;
        }
        return $categories;
    }

    public function get_cas_groups()
    {
        $user = user();
        if($user->account_type == 'teacher'){
            $alloted_groups = $user->alloted_groups;
            $alloted_groups = explode(",",$alloted_groups);
        }else{
            $alloted_groups = [];
        }
        

        foreach($alloted_groups as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->db->or_where('id',$val);
        }
        $categories     =   $this->db->get("cas")->result();
        $catArray   =   ["0"=>"-- Select CAS group --"];
        if(count($categories) > 0){
            foreach($categories as $key=>$val){
                $catArray[$val->id]     =   $val->title;
            }
            $categories     =   $catArray;
        }
        return $categories;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where("id",$id)->delete("cas");
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }   
    
    public function checkSlug($where)
    {
        return $this->db->where($where)->count_all_results("cas");
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (focus on the "minimal" part). You should only post the code that's relevant to the specific issue at hand, example data (incl. database schema if the queries are part of the question), expected result and what currently happens.

Comment: This doesn't look good: `REGEXP ",('.`, and besides, this is a bad way to compare data sets.

Comment: Plus, you are vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql.